# PyroCMS accessing views within a module

Tags: pyrocms

How do I access views within the admin panel of a custom module?

Comment: your question is not clear (at least for me)

Comment: Yeah I mean't to rewrite it. So I have built a custom module which loads a view in the admin panel. I need to be able to load another view when a link is clicked. How do I do this?

Comment: This is still not clear. Add some code so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its very simple in link(anchor tag) you just specify the path to a method in you controller like this

```
<a href="admin/your-controller-name/your-method-name">Your link</a>
```

Now in your-controller you have to create a method your-method-name. in which you have to load a view like this

```
$this->template
  ->set('your-data',$your-data)
  ->build('your-view');
```

if your view is in admin side then you should specify it in build like this

```
build('admin/your-view');
```

Comment: Okay, what is the php var for? and I think I understand this somewhat. is This template build used to insert a view into the admin panel? I tried accessing a link to my view and it just opened in a new page and was not placed in the admin panel

Comment: that variable is used to set any data that you want to access on that view. i think you missed something you have to create a new folder with name "admin" in your "view" folder then you have to write      build('admin/your-view-name');

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to make an AJAX call to the system using jQuery. You can load a link for example to your blog admin:

```
//request blog admin index
$('#link').get('admin/blog', function(data) {
  //Insert response into #element
  $('#element').html(data);
});
```

This will load the entire theme with it. If you just want the view of the blog or the page you wish to load just insert this piece of code in its controller method:

```
  if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
    $this->template->set_layout(FALSE);
  }
```

For the blog/admin the above has already been done, so the jQuery will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the correct answer but your question is vague.

```
$this->load->view('modulename/viewname');
```

You can do that in a Controller or in a View.